# Try to avoid “StaleElementReferenceException” in Selenium - is this approach OK?

Tags: selenium

I'm implementing a lot of Selenium tests. Sometimes, my tests fail due to a `StaleElementReferenceException` so i want to check this approach:

Click Handle:

```
  def clickHandle(expectedCondition: (By) => ExpectedCondition[WebElement], by: By, timeOut: Long): Unit = {

    var count = 0
    var isClicked = false

    breakable {

      while (count < 4 || !isClicked) {
        try {

          val element = driver.findElement...

          element.click()
          isClicked = true
          break

        } catch {

          case e: StaleElementReferenceException => println("Trying to recover from a stale element")
            count = count + 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Get attribute handle:

```
  def getAttributeHandle(expectedCondition: (By) => ExpectedCondition[WebElement], by: By, timeOut: Long, attribute: String): String = {

    var count = 0
    var result = false
    var str = ""

    breakable {

      while (count < 4 || !result) {
        try {

          val element = driver.findElement...

          str = element.getAttribute(attribute)
          result = true
          break

        } catch {

          case e: StaleElementReferenceException => println("Trying to recover from a stale element")
            count = count + 1
        }
      }
    }

    str
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Generally When you get the StaleElementReferenceException it is a page load error. All you need to do is add a page wait in to wait for a text value or whatever is on the page or you could just put in a sleep such as:

```
sleep(10)
```

I use ruby so not 100% sure how to help but generally what I would do when I come across this is add sleeps in or debug your code and add break points in and step through your code to see which point it breaks at.